# how to capture the clicked point before moving a vertex

Tags: arcobjects, c#, arcgis-9.3

I need the location of clicked point before moving a vertex.

IVertexMoved event will provide me the coordinates of the point after vertex is moved but I need before moving.

Please help.

Regards,
Sheethal

Answer (score 1):

You can listen to [`IEditEvents.OnSketchModified`](http://resources.esri.com/help/9.3/arcgisengine/arcobjects/esriEditor/IEditEvents_OnSketchModified.htm) and compare the moved vertices' positions before and after they are moved. An example on the ArcGIS site extends and adds new events that you might also be interested in: [Multiple Vertex Events Sample](http://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=396314f00f5d48bdbdcc04ec6417f8a6)

Comment: I am calling the out of box edit tool in my application to move the vertices of the selected feature. I want to restrict the movement of end vertices, so I need to clicked point coordinates.